# java: HTTP session between a HTTP server and a client

Tags: java, http, httpserver, httpsession

I'm using com.sun.net.HttpServer class to build a http server with java like the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class SimpleHttpServer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8989), 0);
    server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
  }

  static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {

        //Read the request
        InputStream in = httpExchange.getRequestBody();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(in, writer);
        String inputString = writer.toString();

        //prepare the response
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, "Hi my faithful client".length());
        OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        os.write("Hi my faithful client".getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm communicating with this server using this client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException{
        String urlstr = "http://127.0.0.1:8989";
        URL url = new URL(urlstr);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write("Hello HTTP server!! I'm your client1");

        InputStream in  = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and it'fine working.
but what I want now is that the server allows the client to communicate with him for a session that means a sequence of request/response not just only one. So it will be a loop of request/response. For this purpose I tried to add as a first step just one request to the client by adding to it those two lines:

```
writer.flush();
writer.write("Hello HTTP server!! I'm your client2");
```

But it doesn't work. Just the first request is caught by the server.

How can I change the code to achieve my purpose?

Comment: please I need an answer. and thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need to perform just another request or you need a session management with cookies, for example.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin it's a session. just a simple sequence of request of  request/response between the client and the server.
the other request that I added to the client in my example is just a try of a session of two requests. If it works for 2 requests, so it can also for 3, 4, ...
with the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the code below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
public class Test1 {

static String urlstr = "http://127.0.0.1:8989";
public static void main(String argv) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(urlstr);
    Test1 t = new Test1();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        t.sendRequest("Hello HTTP server!! I'm your client" + i, url);
    }

}

private void sendRequest(String strToSend, URL url) throws IOException{

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(strToSend);

    InputStream in  = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

}